# sum and sum quadratic sum of complex sequence

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $ {(v_n)}_{n \in N} $ be a complex sequence such that $|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{v_n}|<\infty$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{|v_n|^2}<\infty$

I would like to know if $ \frac{|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{v_n}|}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{|v_n|^2}}<\infty$ for each $v_n$

Any suggest is welcome... thanks.

Comment: ??? Unless $v_n=0$ for all $n$, it's obvious

Comment: You are asking if there is a universal constant for all such sequences right?

Comment: yes, if for each sequence

Comment: If you are asking for a uniform bound (a single universal constant that holds for every sequence), then your quantifiers are wrong -- that is not what you asking, either in the question or the comments.

Comment: Also, the answer (to the "uniform bound") is no. Start with a sequence $(v_n)_n$ satisfying the assumption,  define the sequence $(\lambda v_n)_n$, and see what happens to the ratio when $\lambda \to 0^+$

Comment: i beg pardon, i made just confusion, i would know if that quotient is bounded. thanks for your answer

Comment: Read the above comments. For each (non-identically zero) sequence satisfying your assumptions, the ratio is finite; but there is no single upper bound on the ratio that works for all such sequences at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If the numerator is finite, and the denominator is finite and nonzero, then the quotient is finite.

Comment: i mean if for each sequence that quotient is finite